# How do I create custom "association methods" in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I've read [this article,](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2006/12/03/extend-your-activerecord-association-methods) but it's for Rails 1.x.

I'd really like to create my own association methods:

```
user = User.find(1)

# Example of a normal association method
user.replies.create(:body => 'very informative. plz check out my site.')

# My association method
user.replies.find_by_spamminess(:likelihood => :very)
```

In Rails 3, what's the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rails 3 way of doing things is often to not use find methods, but rather scopes, which delays the actual database call until you start iterating over the collection.

Guessing at your first example, I would do:

in class Reply ...

```
  scope :spaminess, lambda {|s| where(:likelyhood => s) }
```

and then using it:

```
 spammy_messages = user.replies.spaminess(:very)
```

or to use it in a view

```
spammy_messages.each do |reply|
   ....
end
```

Comment: +1 What if the rules for the scope *require* pulling from the database? For example, what if you had to pull associated models and perform logic on them? Would all of that still be delayed until the results were iterated over? I suppose I felt that sort of logic belonged in the model, and quick Googling revealed that Railscast seems to agree (http://asciicasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3).

Comment: The scope is in the model, and yes, it can use multiple relations.

Comment: I hadn't noticed your comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think I found it!

If you search for "association extensions" the Rails API page for [ActiveRecord::Assications](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), you'll see that this is the syntax (copied from that link):

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people do
    def find_or_create_by_name(name)
      first_name, last_name = name.split(" ", 2)
      find_or_create_by_first_name_and_last_name(first_name, last_name)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: As this is exactly how rails1, does it, what made you think it didn't work anymore?