# Use of HABTM along with has_many :through - Need Help Identifying Where I've Gone Wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many, has-many-through

About an hour ago i asked a question on rails associations:
[Question on Proper Associations in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970047/question-on-proper-associations-in-rails/)

The accepted answer from that question got me thinking about relationships more deeply and I'd like to present the SO community with this situation.

My previous question used poet, poem, and printing as the models... For this one let's use the music industry:

The models are:

- Artist
- Album
- Song
- Genre

The following statements are to be considered true:

1. An album can have multiple artists - ie Metallica and Pantera release an xmas album
2. A song can belong to multiple albums - ie Yellow Submarine is on the original album as well as a number of "Greatest hits" albums from The Beatles
3. An individual song can also have multiple "featured" artists that differ from the album artist - ie Snoop Dogg owns the album but does a song featuring Harry Connick Jr.  Or an even better example is when a DJ releases an album where ALL the songs are by other artists.
4. Artist, Album, and Song can all be classified under multiple/different Genres - ie Brian Setzer Orchestra is categorized as "Swing", one of their albums could be "Swing, Rockabilly" and an individual song on that album could be "Jump Blues".

When digging through this problem, I immediately see that models such as Artist & Genre can be "reused".  We would NOT want to save a artist's information more than once -- so for example in the event we have a song w/ both a main artist and featured artist BOTH artists' information should live in the DB's "Artist" table.

Additionally, when reviewing the "featured" artist aspect (statement #2) it seems we have an additional attribute that should be on the association -- something like a "featured" flag.

Here is how i think the associations should be setup -- and also the apex of my post.... is this right, and how can i make it better?

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :albums
  has_and_belongs_to_many :genres
  has_many :featurings
  has_many :features, :through => :featurings, :conditions => "featured = true"
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :artists
  has_and_belongs_to_many :songs
  has_many :featurings
  has_many :featured_artists, :through => :featurings, :conditions => "featured = true"
end

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :genres
  has_many :artists
  has_many :featurings
  has_many :featured_artists, :through => :featurings, :conditions => "featured = true"
end

class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :artists
  has_and_belongs_to_many :songs
end

class Featurings < ActiveRecord::Base
  # the db table for this class should have a "featured" boolean.
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :album
  belongs_to :song
end
```

As usual, huge thanks to those who take the time to read and give input! it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more of a discussion than a question, but I'll attempt to address your concerns. I am not testing any of your code, so these are just my thoughts.

```
(Artist) has_any_belongs_to_many :genres
```

Should you need a separate table for this? The information is already stored through the association between songs and genres. Unless artists can belong to genres despite not having songs in said genres, you should not reproduce this information in another HABTM association.

Vice versa, the opposite association may be redundant:

```
(Genre) has_any_belongs_to_many :artists
```

As for your design of the featuring aspect, it seems that having a feature with the flag featured set to true is also redundant. However, that is because of the naming, so if I were you I'd rename it to Release instead (songs can be released on multiple albums). If you think of the featured flag as existing between the artist and the song, you should add the flag to the enjoining entity (forgot the term for this).

However, since it is expressed as a HABTM association, there is no intervening model. Thus, you will have to convert this to use has_many on both Song and Artist, with the intervening model containing belong_to associations as well as a featured flag. This is actually the Release model.

This (again no testing has been done) cuts down your models to this:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :albums
  has_many :releases
  has_many :songs, :through => :releases
  has_many :albums, :through => :releases
  has_many :featured_songs, through => :releases, :conditions => "featured = true"
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :artists
  has_many :releases
  has_many :songs, :through => :releases
  has_many :artists, :through => :releases
end

class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :song
  belongs_to :album
  # there should be a featured boolean
end

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :genres
  has_many :releases
  has_many :artists, :through => :releases
  has_many :albums, :through => :releases
  has_many :featured_artists, through => :releases, :conditions => "featured = true"
end

class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :songs
end
```

Comment: I dont have edit privs but there's a typo: "has_any_belongs_to_many".  thanks for responding.  Reviewing the code.

Comment: Fixed the typos, plus I don't expect this code will work out of the box. It's more theoretical than anything =)

Comment: Should featured_artists and featured_songs actually be scopes rather than associations on the model?

Comment: If it is just a matter of style, I'd prefer to use scopes. I'm not sure if there are any performance considerations. In the past, named_scopes were declared dead, see http://www.railway.at/2010/03/09/named-scopes-are-dead/

Comment: Jaryl, follow up question:  Using the Artist class as an example... Why did you keep `has_and_belongs_to_many :albums` when `has_many :albums, :through => :releases` should give access to the albums?

Comment: Shucks, good catch, it should be removed; same goes for has_and_belongs_to_many :artists in the Album model.

Comment: Jaryl, i think i have your example almost working with some modifications.  How would you go about flagging an artist as "featured" on a song?

Comment: Hmm, the Release model should have featured as a flag, which would tell you if the artist was featured on a released song, on a given album. This should already be working, with the given code. Perhaps I am missing something, so fill me in with more details.

Comment: I think this code explains my (evolved) troubles a bit better.  Basically what i would like to do is say `Artist.first.featured_song.create(:title => "blah")` and have the `release.featured` flag set to true automatically.  Here is what happens when i do it: http://pastie.org/private/zhhvhuipf2m93k5sg4xnzq  and ideas?

Comment: You could create your own association method, see [old article](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2006/12/3/extend-your-activerecord-association-methods), by using [scopes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213407/how-do-i-create-custom-association-methods-in-rails-3). I'm not sure if you could add a custom method that creates though, you'd have to try it out on your own but I hope that it's possible!

Answer (score 2):

I am not a fan of HABTM associations. So I have used has_many association. To address Genre belonging to Album, Song etc I have used polymorphic associations. Solution is quite complex. But it addresses all the requirements:

```
class Artist

  has_many :genre_links, :as => :genre_holder
  has_many :genres, :through => :genre_links

  has_many :artist_links

  has_many :albums, :through => :artist_links, 
                    :source => :artist_holder, :source_type => "Album"

  has_many :songs, :through => :artist_links, 
                    :source => :artist_holder, :source_type => "Song"


  has_many :featured_songs, :through => :artist_links, 
                    :source => :artist_holder, :source_type => "Song",
                    :conditions => {:featured => true}

end
```

Use the `:source_type` option to create associations for albums and songs.

```
class Genre
  has_many :genre_links
  has_many :albums, :through => :genre_links, 
                    :source => :genre_holder, :source_type => "Album"

  has_many :songs, :through => :genre_links, 
                    :source => :genre_holder, :source_type => "Song"

end

class GenreLink
  belongs_to :genre_holder, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :genre
end

class ArtistLink
  # featured
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :artist_holder, :polymorphic => true 
end
```

We need a custom SQL to get the featured songs for an album.

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :genre_links, :as => :genre_holder
  has_many :genres, :through => :genre_links

  has_many :artist_links, :as => :artist_holder, 
             :condition => {:featured => false}
  has_many :artists, :through => :artist_links


  has_many :album_songs 
  has_many :songs, :through => :album_songs

  has_many :featured_artists, :class => "Artist", :custom_sql => '
    SELECT A.* FROM artists A WHERE A.id IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT B.artist_id FROM artist_links B 
      WHERE B.artist_holder_type = "Song" AND B.featured = 1 AND
            B.artist_holder_id IN (#{song_ids.join(",")}))' 

end
```

Now to rest of the classes:

```
class AlbumSong
  belongs_to :album
  belongs_to :song
end

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :genre_links, :as => :genre_holder
  has_many :genres, :through => :genre_links

  has_many :album_songs 
  has_many :albums, :through => :album_songs

  has_many :artist_links, :as => :artist_holder, 
             :condition => {:featured => :false}
  has_many :artists, :through => :artist_links

  has_many :featured_artist_links, :class => "ArtistLink", 
             :as => :artist_holder, :condition => {:featured => :true }
  has_many :featured_artists, :through => :featured_artist_links, 
             :source => :artist

end
```

An artist can be associated with an album and/or a song.

```
album1.artists << artist1
song1.artists << artist1
```

**Flagging a song as featured:**

*Rails 3*

```
song1.featured_artists << artist2
```

Rails automatically sets the hash condition parameters of the association during create. So there is nothing else to do.

*Rails 2.x*

```
song1.featured_artist_links.create(:featured => true, :artist => artist2)
```

Comment: How would you go about flagging an artist as "featured" on a song?

Comment: @KandadaBoggu - you say "I am not a fan of HABTM associations." - as I see it this is fairly key to the question and should be discussed more. Please explain to the OP why you believe HABTM are bad practice and just as importantly *why* your "quite complex" solution is better.

Comment: @Jeremy The solution is complex not because of the HABTM. It is complex because the requirement states that `Genre` can belong to `Song` or/and `Album` and `Artist` can belong to `Alubm` or/and `Song`. Other interesting aspect is a `Song` might not include the artists from its `Alubm`. Why do I prefer `has_many` over `has_and_belongs_to_many`? Implementing HABTM using dual `has_many` allows you to store additional attributes along with the relationship(eg: `featured` in this case). In most of the cases this need eventually creeps in.

Comment: @KandadaBoggu - I think you're 100% right with the key issue with HABTM: it only works as long as it's just recording the existence of the links. As soon as more info is needed then you're into has_many :through territory, often so quickly (for me it's usually before my data model has left the pencil-and-paper stage) that it makes sense to go straight there.